# Difference in various local ports

Tags: linux, unix, networking, tcp, netstat

When I run `$ netstat -ntlp` I get the following output:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

To make sense of the output I have a few questions:

1. What is the difference in the "Foreign Address" between `0.0.0.0:*` and `:::*`?
2. Why do some ports, such as `22` have an entry in both tcp and tcp6?
3. For the local address, what is the difference between `:::` and `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` (and `localhost`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference in the "Foreign Address" between 0.0.0.0:* and :::*?

In the first case it is is IPv4, in the second one IPv6.

> Why do some ports, such as 22 have an entry in both tcp and tcp6?

Because the server is listening with two different sockets on IPv4 and IPv6. Some servers try to use a single socket for both (not supported on all OS), some use different sockets. In case of OpenSSH: it supports listening on multiple IP:port anyway and it also originates from OpenBSD where listening for IPv4 and IPv6 with a single socket is not supported (explicit decision, for security).

> For the local address, what is the difference between ::: and 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 (and localhost)? Are these all the same, or why are they referenced differently?

`:::` is the ANY address for IPv6 while `0.0.0.0` is the any address for IPv4 - with these listener address the server will accept traffic on all IP addresses it has (i.e. all interfaces: local, ethernet, wifi, VPN...). `127.0.0.1` is localhost for IPv4, i.e. only connections from the local machine are possible. The IPv6 localhost would be `::1`. What `localhost` means depends on the entries in `/etc/hosts`, typically the same as `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response. So, more or less, `localhost` is a sort of alias that is defined in /etc/hosts?

Comment: @David542: yes, kind of. One could all it whatever but `localhost` is traditionally used.

Comment: thx a lot ... ::1 vs 127.0.0.1 helped :)